# VanillaJS - Change style of specific button with same class, when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, css

I have 3 buttons with same class(myBtn), I want to change the background color of the button I clicked using querySelectorAll and addEventListener.

I'm making a bigger project this is just an example of my problem, I'm into pure javascript and i don't wanna use onClick method in my html for some reason.

```js
var a = document.querySelectorAll('myBtn')[2];
a.addEventListener("click", callFunc());
function callFunc() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to change its background color.</p>

<button id="myBtn">uno</button>
<button id="myBtn">dos</button>
<button id="myBtn">tres</button>
```

Comment: `id` on html element must be unique per document.
`queryselectorall` return an array you need to iterate it and add the event listener.

Comment: 1. Change to class and not id, 2 you need a dot 3. You need to remove the () from the event handler assignment : `var a = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn')[2];
a.addEventListener("click", callFunc);
function callFunc() {
  this.style.backgroundColor = "red";
}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- ID should be **unique**. Use classes.
- Create a class (i.e: `.red`) in your stylesheet and use `.classList.toggle()` or `.classList.add()`
- `querySelectorAll()` returns a NodeList collection of Elements. Use a `.forEach()`
- PS: `[2]` will give you only one element, not *"... of the one I clicked"*

```js
const myBtn = document.querySelectorAll('.myBtn');
const changeBackground = ev => ev.currentTarget.classList.toggle('red'); 

myBtn.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', changeBackground));
```

```css
.red { background: #f00; }
```

```html
<button class="myBtn">uno</button>
<button class="myBtn">dos</button>
<button class="myBtn">tres</button>
```